# How to Make Image Do All 3: Cover (left-to-right), Resize, and Scroll

Tags: css

How do you make an image: cover (left-to-right), resize (keeping correct aspect ratio), and scroll?  Thus far, searching discovers results that do one or two of these features, but not all three simultaneously.  Here is the CSS associated with my latest failed attempt.  The same CSS (below) was used in a div and the result was still unsuccessful.  An example of the attempted effect is the image of wheat here (http://nlbcg.weebly.com).

```
body {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background-color: #ffffff;
background: url('Image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
// background-attachment: scroll;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by scroll? The image scrolling that I know of is when the image appears to stay in the same position while the page is scrolled up/down. However your posted example at http://nlbcg.weebly.com , the background wheat field image, does not seem do this, so can you elaborate what you mean by scroll? Thanks

Comment: user454038 - The effect in the referenced example has; I think, been correctly understood by Alex (below).  However, even with a separate div element I have not been able to reproduce what is seen in the referenced example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div {
position: relative;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 700px;
background: url('Image.jpg') no-repeat center center;   
background-size: 100% !important;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's not the background image that scrolls, but the container. Give det container a height than your're good to go.

Comment: Alex - You have; I think, correctly understood the desired effect noted in the referenced example.  However, even with a separate div element I have not been able to reproduce what is seen in the example.  Speculating - it seems to be the CSS being used in the separate div element.  Getting the image in the background of the separate div is easy enough, but making all 3 aspects work simultaneously (cover left-to-right, resize while keeping correct aspect ratio, and scroll), as seen in the example, is illuding me.

Comment: I think this is what you need:                                                                  .big-image{
 width:100%;
 height:100vh;
 background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center;
 background-size:cover;
}.  In your example the image is used as a background-image for a container div that has a width of 100%, a height that covers 100% of the browser window at all time, and it is responsive.